# Toggle doesn't work - java

Tags: java, toggle

I am trying this to toggle the value of key1 in but I get the same value all the time. What am I doing wrong here?

```
boolean jsonText =  true;
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

public void setjsonObject(boolean val){
    this.jsonText = val;
}

public Boolean getjsonObject(){
    return this.jsonText;
}

@POST("/hello")
    @PermitAll
    public String hello(String text) {

    try {   
        if (jsonObj.has("key1")) {
            boolean val = !jsonObj.getBoolean("key1");
            jsonObj.remove("key1");
            jsonObj.put("key1", val);
        } else {
            jsonObj.put("key1", true);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "some result";

    }
```

Am I resetting the "`key1`" `boolean` value somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

you are creating new JSON object every time:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
```

so it never has any value for "key1" and it is always set to true after your hello code.